# Create link "node" instead of "NavigationNode"

Tags: 2013, powershell, spnavigationnode

I'm able to create subtitles in my sites. I create title under others, this create subtitles.
I use `New-Object Microsoft.SharePoint.Navigation.SPNavigationNode` which create titles, but what the object if I want to create a "link node" instead of a title ? Which is possible in graphical mode.

Is there something like `New-Object Microsoft.SharePoint.Navigation.SPLinkNode` ?

Hope I'm pretty clear =)

Nico.

Comment: A SPNavigationNode is a "link" node. [SPNavigationNode.Url](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.sharepoint.navigation.spnavigationnode.url.aspx) specifies where it goes

Comment: @Per Jakobsen : I agree. But when you put permissions to a library, if a NavigationNode point at it, everybody can see the Node. If it's a "link", only people who have permissions see it. In graphical mode there is a difference... I'm sure in PS there is one too.

Answer (score 1):

The Security Trimming of SPNavigatinNode is controlled by th [IsExternal](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.sharepoint.navigation.spnavigationnode.isexternal.aspx) property:

If this is `false` then the Url is only shown if the user has access to the list.

`IsExternal` is specified as the third parameter to the [contructor](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms415159.aspx)

Comment: Thanks for your answer, gonna test it tomorrow :) Looks great !